# Error on doing SOAP service call using java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsimport

I've HTTPS web service. I can generate java classes with wsimport but when I invoke the service I receive the following exception:

> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.UnknownHostException: abc.xyz.ca.com
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:117)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:208)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:124)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:178)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.query(Unknown Source)
>           at com.westpac.idm.clarityuserprovisioning.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:29)
>       Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: cppm6002-dev.ondemand.ca.com
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
>           at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
>           at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:264)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1340)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1315)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:104)

My class that invoke the service is something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    try {
        Auth auth = new Auth();
        auth.setUsername("username");
        auth.setPassword("password");

        WbcActiveUsersQuery query_code = new WbcActiveUsersQuery();
        query_code.setCode("wbc_active_users");

        WbcActiveUsersQueryService service = new WbcActiveUsersQueryService();
        WbcActiveUsersQueryPort port = service.getWbcActiveUsersQueryService();

        WbcActiveUsersQueryResult result =  port.query(query_code, auth);

    }catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I tried to use SoapUI to call the webservice, its working fine there.
[image]

Can anybody help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`java.net.UnknownHostException: abc.xyz.ca.com` indicates you are not using the correct hostname/url of the service.

Please use the correct URL.

For proxy use:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port);
System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "localhost|127.0.0.1");
```

Alternatively, you can also set the proxy to the server where you have deployed your client code to call Soap service.

Comment: Can you update the question with screenshot of the Soap UI where it works clearly showing the exact URL used there?

Comment: Updated the soapUI. The URL is inside corporate network and https method is used while invoking service.

Comment: Where exactly the host `abc.xyz.ca.com` is coming from? It is there in the logs? Is it present in the wsdl file or anywhere in your code?

Comment: I changed it hide the actual URL

Comment: How can set proxy for this. If i disable proxy in SOAP I get the same exception

Comment: Updated my answer to include how to set proxy

Comment: try without setting "http.nonProxyHosts"

Comment: I am using HTTPS URL

Comment: You might to want to import the certificate if using HTTPS url but the error log doesn't seem to be related to it.